# understanding the use of javascript statements

Tags: javascript, statements

This question is not meant to find a solution for the task but to ***understand*** as the title says.
I could not categorize the question. Without further ado. I began practicing Javascript on the website freecodecamp.org.My main concern is the set up of the function from freecodecamp.org:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

Keep in mind that all these three are statements.
So when I dug deeper the website w3schools.com stated that:

> JavaScript statements are composed of:Values, Operators, Expressions, Keywords, and Comments.

```
The for loop has the following syntax:
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}
```

w3schools.com displays strings as statements.
My questions are:
- Does that mean Objects can also become statements? (Since values are considered to be statements, I am referring to the Name-Value-pairs).
- How are statements and parameters connected with each other? (since both are 'value-holders')

Comment: You're messing up [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)) and [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)).

Comment: A `for` loop is a statement but the parts inside the loop header are not statements. They can only be *expressions* (`initialization` can also be a variable declaration). An *object literal* is an expression. There is also an *expression statement* which allows the use of an expression in a statement context. So yes, you can use an object literal everywhere a statement can be used, but that doesn’t make an object literal a statement. I’m not sure knowing this is helpful if you don’t have a good understanding of expressions and statements already.

Comment: @FelixKling I do understand parts of statements and expressions. I am a beginner so giving me only parts of the puzzle is creating confusion. I tried to the copy-past learning methode like everybody else, that did not made it stick for verylong. However if I have the whole information then understanding it will be easy. For example: the usage of numbers. I knew only that mathematical operations(eg: addition, subtraction, devision, and multiplication)can occure. I didnt know about  numbers create bevaiour, or decimal numbers care allowed or how a function was written.

Comment: I was mainly worried that throwing in the term `ExpressionStatement` would create more confusion than it would be helping.

Comment: @FelixKling dont sweat it. I was referring to the educational setup from where I get/got my knowledge. thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does that mean Objects can also become statements?

The answer to that  is **no.**

I get what you mean: Of course you can use objects to achieve "statement/operator-like meaning" within a programming language, but these properties only exist in semantics and do not become part of the syntax as actual statements or operators of the language.

There is actually a big difference between [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)) and [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) when it comes to the inner logic programming languages. I don't want to dig deeper in it because that would be a bit [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and I'm also not an expert in Computer Science.

Comment: For no misunderstanding, I added my answer only to fulfill your answer and answer OP's second question asked in post

Comment: @Vepthy Yes, I already got that. Also a very good answer in itself!

Answer (score 3):

> Does that mean Objects can also become statements? (Since values are considered to be statements, I am referring to the Name-Value-pairs)

Nope. From w3schools.com, this is how they explain a statement:

> This statement **tells the browser to write "Hello Dolly."** inside an HTML element with id="demo":
>   `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello Dolly.";`

The reason why `for` loop contains three "statements":

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}
```

Is because those statements tell the browser what to do:

> Statement 1 is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.
>
> Statement 2 defines the condition for executing the code block.
>
> Statement 3 is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

---

> How are statements and parameters connected with each other?

They aren't.

- Parameters are used in functions and behave as local variables in them;
- Statements tell the browser what to do and are **executed** one by one.

---

References:

[JS Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_statements.asp)

[JS for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

[JS Function parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)